# Nested set model with client-specific nodes

Tags: mysql, mariadb, nested-sets

I have the following case. I am using a nested set model to store hierarchical data. The model is pretty much the same apart from the fact that I also want to add the option of having a specific subcategory to be available only to a certain client(s). Editing the table would be done externally from a VB.NET app which would then send the new table back to the database.

I have thought of two different options to accomplish that. The first is to add a new client_id field which concatenates the client ids. Then I would perform a query to look for the specific number in the string. The #1 refers to all users whereas, a number different from that refers to a specific client.

```
+-------------+----------------------+-----+-----+---------+
| category_id | name                 | lft | rgt |client_id|
+-------------+----------------------+-----+-----+----------
|           1 | MAINCAT1             |   1 |  20 |        1|
|           2 | subcat1              |   2 |   9 |      2;4|
|           3 | subcat2              |   3 |   4 |        3|
|           4 | subcat3              |   5 |   6 |        1|
|           5 | subcat4              |   7 |   8 |      2;3|
|           6 | MAINCAT2             |  10 |  19 |        1|
|           7 | subcat1              |  11 |  14 |        1|
|           8 | subcat2              |  12 |  13 |        1|
|           9 | subcat3              |  15 |  16 |      3;4|
|          10 | subcat4              |  17 |  18 |      3;4|
+-------------+----------------------+-----+-----+---------+
```

The second option is to add a new field for every client and use some sort of a mark e.g 1/0 to enable/disable the categories.

```
+-------------+----------------------+-----+-----+---------+---------+
| category_id | name                 | lft | rgt |client_2 |client_3
+-------------+----------------------+-----+-----+---------+---------+
|           1 | MAINCAT1             |   1 |  20 |        1|        1|
|           2 | subcat1              |   2 |   9 |        0|        1|
|           3 | subcat2              |   3 |   4 |        0|        1|
|           4 | subcat3              |   5 |   6 |        1|        0|
|           5 | subcat4              |   7 |   8 |        1|        0|
|           6 | MAINCAT2             |  10 |  19 |        1|        1|
|           7 | subcat1              |  11 |  14 |        0|        1|
|           8 | subcat2              |  12 |  13 |        0|        1|
|           9 | subcat3              |  15 |  16 |        1|        0|
|          10 | subcat4              |  17 |  18 |        0|        1|
+-------------+----------------------+-----+-----+---------+---------+
```

I would prefer going for the first option as it doesn't require adding/removing fields. I suspect performing queries would be slower, however I don't plan to make the table very lengthy. Which method do you think is more adequate?

Comment: Don't go with either. Go with lft,rgt adjacency lists. The csv would be ridiculous. The 2nd one would be a career ender.

Comment: I am already using lft,rgt.

Comment: don't go with csv in the top chunk, last column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first option means finding the matching id in a potentially very large string (and ultimately limiting the number of clients who can see that category). If you must do this (and I would advise against it) then make the list comma separated as you can then at least use the FIND_IN_SET() function.

The 2nd option seems to require a column per client, which will be a nightmare as you get more clients.

I would suggest you have another table which has multiple rows per category, one for each client that can see that category. Using a simple join you can check that a category can be seen by the relevant client.

EDIT - 2 table solution would mean adding a table linking categories to clients. Simple table like this:-

```
CREATE TABLE category_client
(
    category_id INT(11),
    client_id   INT(11),
    PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`, `client_id`),
    KEY `client_id` (`client_id`) 
);

INSERT INTO TABLE category_client (client_id, category_id) VALUES
(1, 1,
(2, 2),
(2, 4),
(3, 3),
(4, 1),
(5, 2),
(5, 3),
(6, 1),
(7, 1),
(8, 1),
(9, 3),
(9, 4),
(10, 3),
(10, 4);
```

Comment: Hello, could you elaborate please?

Comment: @StanislavLazarov - added the suggested 2nd table